# Как достать картинку из папки через PIL на хостинге?

Tags: python, сервер, дерево, pil

Пишу код на pythonanywhere, есть такая строка:

```
field = Image.open('images/field.jpg')
```

На её выполнении вылетает ошибка.

```
  File "/home/programalpharunning/mysite/game/painter.py", line 3, in <module>
    field = Image.open('images/field.jpg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2766, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/field.jpg'
```

Структура папок такая:

[image: Структура папок такая:]

Сам исполняемый код срабатывает при импорте. Пробовал абсолютный путь. Просто на компьютере такая же связка работает.

Comment: Посмотрите значение `os.getcwd()` чтобы увидеть в какой папке работает скрипт

Comment: '/home/programalpharunning' — Рабочая директория, получается